# How to *install* two specific versions of Unison without installing unison-all or any other version than those two specific versions

Tags: unison

Please do not mark as duplicate because somewhere else someone says that installing `unison-all` will achieve the same.

I am not asking "How can I *use* several versions of Unison in the same machine?". The answer to that would be: install the package `unison-all` (which, by the way, is a poor solution because it does not allow to use all versions, but only a few recent versions).

I am asking how to install two specific versions of Unison and use them separately.

Please understand the difference between

> How can I **use** two different versions of Unison in the same machine?

and

> How can I **install** two different specific versions (from two different specific packages) in such a way that both can be used independently on the same machine?

Note that in the later, you would only be able to use those two specific versions and nothing else, whereas in the fully different first case you would have access to several versions.

Comment: I know what is coming now, but I have to try anyway. Because of sheer faith in the human nature, I have to try. Marked as duplicate in 3, 2, 1... And downvoted too. Lots of negative points. Sigh...

Comment: I think your pessimism is a bit unfounded. :P You can find the source for past versions of Unison [here](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases). I'm pretty sure when you install Unison from source it'll install a binary `/usr/bin/unison-VERSION-NUMBER`, you can just install whichever versions you want and they'll get their own executable in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install any versions you want from source. Download the source for any versions of Unison you want [from this page](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases), compile and install them one at a time. Then after each install, go into the installation directory (probably `/usr/bin/`) and copy the newly installed `unison` executable to `unison-VERSIONNUMBER` or something. And then you can run any version of Unison you want by just specifying the version number.

If you want to avoid installing Unison from source and install different versions through your package manager instead, then your question is much more about your package manager than it is about Unison.